# Using new-item to create folder occasionally throws error in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Windows 2016 Server with Powershell 5.0 installed on it. I'm trying to create a folder on a network file share (which is also on the same server, but I access the file share with \server\backup instead of D:\backup) with Powershell command below.

However the code below occasionally throw errors.

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid Path: '\\server\backup\PSBackup\newFolder'.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPath..ctor(String path)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlServerProvider.NewItem(String path, String type, Object newItem)
   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.NewItemPrivate(CmdletProvider providerInstance, String path, String type, Object content, CmdletProviderContext context)
```

I have a powershell script which creates folders in an order, the same code creates the first folder, but throws error for the second folder creation.

Did you ever face such a problem when creating folder on a network share? By the way the same powershell script works without any problem on my dev machine (Windows 2012 R2) and Windows 2008 R2 servers.

```
$rootFolder = "\\server\backup\PSBackup"
$folderName = "newFolder"

$createdDirectory = New-Item -Path $rootFolder -ItemType "directory" -Name $folderName
```

Comment: What happens when you do like `$createdDirectory = New-Item -LiteralPath (Join-Path -Path $rootFolder -ChildPath $folderName) -ItemType Directory` ?

Comment: Does the path have any square brackets?  `[ ]`

Comment: @js2010 no path doesn't have brackets.

Comment: @Theo no LiteralPath also didn't work. Actually my code above works most of the time, but throws errors for another run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When **Path** parameter is changed **"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$($rootFolder)"** instead of **$rootFolder**, code worked as expected.

There should be a problem with passing remote folder as parameter.

```
$createdDirectory = New-Item -Path "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$($rootFolder)" -ItemType "directory" -Name $folderName
```

Comment: I use sqlserver PS module to backup my database just before problematic folder creation occurs. As this module changes ptah to SQLSERVER:\ folder creation throws error.I define $rootFolder variable before SQL Server backup operation. However after SQL Server operation this variable becomes null.

Comment: Root problem is that sqlserver module that I use to backup databases causes path to change. This causes $rootFolder variable to lose its value. I called Push-Location  function just before using sqlserver module and then called Pop-Location just after stop my job with it, and go on.